# Create a WebApp to capture ftp upload request and forward it as http upload request instead

Tags: c#, http, ftp

On our web server (IIS) we can't install a fully functional ftp server for security reasons. But our clients use a programm that can only transfer their xml files via ftp protocol, they can't send an http request to our server. I need to create a webapp that could recieve ftp requests for file upload, acting like ftp server, but with very limited capabilities. It will get the xml file and resend it via http protocol(aka form post request). Any ideas on how to achive this and tips for existing sources and APIs (or just a more reasonable aproach) for php or C# will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can't install an FTP server, but you want to write a program that is an FTP server (I'm not sure what the difference between "imitating" and "being one" is)?

Comment: The only ftp-server-thing that my program must do is recieve ftp file as a binary stream, that just goes to memory and nowhere else. But wait... this means ftp authorization and ftp session and a system that will transfer a file in a separate packages and probably many other stuff that I didn't think of )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woah, you cant use an `ftp server`, so you want to fake an `ftp server`, which is basically just using an `ftp server`. *scratches head*.

This is not going to work

**However**

One way might be :

- Uing a remote `ftp` location (outside your network) which is secure.
- Your client uploads to that server.
- you poll that remote server for the file
- Delete said file when finished

This is not pretty but it might work

Comment: Thats exatly what we are doing right now)) just want to skip that part where the file goes to a disk and then gets deleted.

Comment: @plavozont the problem is if the network admins dont want to let you map through a port for security reasons there is no much you can do

Comment: the port is not closed, it's just nothing in there... and the admin is my fellow ))

Comment: @plavozont ahh i see what you are doing, well maybe best to use an FTP server lib, there are plenty around, then when you receive the file just pop it off to your http address

Comment: ftp server lib, great!.. that dispels the darkness (seriously, no irony here). Enough to take the first step! Keep me up to date if you've got something else helpful !

Comment: after three nights of subconscious analyze of this I ended up with a thought that we should ask our clients to create their own ftp server to put xml file to, and write themselves a programm, that will get it from there, send to us via http and relieve us of this headache.)))

Comment: @plavozont Yeah it sounds like a very good solution, that way it can be local, and reduce some of the degrees of fredom